# MySQL - Row size too large error while dropping the column

Tags: mysql, text, blob, innodb

I have a really wide table. I need to refactor the code at some point but this is not an option at the moment. I need to get rid of one column, a varcher(1024) and to make things better for the table size modify one column from varchar(1024) to TEXT.

The problem is that any alter table command on the table, either drop column or modify column ends in following error:
"Row size too large. The maximum row size for the used table type, not counting BLOBs, is 8126. This includes storage overhead, check the manual. You have to change some columns to TEXT or BLOBs"

What can I do? I understand that mysql is suggesting I change some columns to TEXT vat doing so ends up in the same error.

I have already set 
innodb_log_file_size=2G
innodb_log_buffer_size=2G
innodb_file_per_table
innodb_file_format = Barracuda
internal_tmp_disk_storage_engine=MyISAM;

Comment: What about creating a new table and copy the data?

Comment: Sure Paul, it may work. I will try it. But I am surprised that this is happening. Why would mysql error out when we are changing the columns to a type TEXT. So if the table is at the capacity then you are at the dead end? It can not alter table to alleviate the load but it can also not function anymore. I think I may be missing some setting.

Comment: I don't know and can only guess. You want to "change" the type. But internally MySQL might need to create a new column with the new type, copy the data and then drop the old column. In this case creating the new column might fail due to the row size limit.

Comment: I've voted to migrate this question to http://dba.stackexchange.com - I think it's a good question, but you should get better help there.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to `ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC`.  In this mode, wide columns are stored as a pointer to an off-row area.  In the default mode, they are stored as 767 bytes plus a pointer, hence more likely to lead to the error you received.

If you need to discuss this further, I need to know which version you are running, plus `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, plus the failing `ALTER`.